# Is sql injection possible on this websocket?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, websocket

I was testing a websocket when i found an add to cart request like the following

```
["{\"ITEMS\":{\"ITEM\":[{\"package_id\":\"123\",\"customer_type\":\"3\",\"qty\":1,\"}"]
```

I tried to edit the value of the parameter `qty` to `-1` and send the request. In response i received this error:

```
a["{\"error_msg\":\"Failed to add ITEM[0]: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'qty' at row 1\",\"http_response_code\":\"500\",[...]"}"]
```

---

`Out of range value for column 'qty' at row 1`

This error should be a MySql error. So i tried to use other sql injection payloads but it doesn't seems to work.

I'm getting `@request_type was not defined` errors with sql injection payloads.

What payload can i use to verify this websocket is vulnerable to sql injection?

Answer (score 1):

For sql injection to work, you need the program to construct a string.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemid = "$VALUE"`

So, `$VALUE = "-1"` will produce:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemid = "-1"`

`$VALUE = "1\" OR itemid is not null and "a" = \"a"`

will fill out as:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemid = "1\" OR itemid is not null and a = \"a"`

Which should return everything......

However, they may be using bind parameters and since -1 and 1 are both integers, the binding logic will simple fill in the value and not let you break out of the quotes.

```
res = sql.query(q, [$VALUE])

if (res.error) return res.error
```

in that case, if $VALUE is the injection string, the library will not interpret the other clauses as commands. It will treat the whole value as a single variable. It doesn't do string manipulation, but keeps the command part and the variable part completely separate. It says to mysql:

1. here is the command: `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemid = ?"`
2. the command has one variable. here is the first variable: `$VALUE`

And because it's the server, and it has a ton of logic to figure out what the command part is and the variable parts are, it says ok, thanks for keeping those separate, it makes my job easier and i won't parse the variable as a command. and so the extra "and"s, "or"s, and "="s are not interpreted as commands but as the one value.

Comment: I tried with your example payload

`$VALUE = "1\" OR itemid is not null and "a" = \"a"`
-
and it doesn't respond. I got `no response from heartbeat` error.
-
Do you think it may be vulnerable or not?

Comment: I think you might have crashed the server, and if you did, yeah, it's vulnerable.

Comment: If i refresh the page the same request is sent when i click on `add to cart`. I think that the socket fails to understand the request and drop the response. Does that mean that it's vulnerable?

Comment: If you found an unhandled bug, that could be a signal there is a bug or vulnerability in the application. Keep trying.

Comment: @DispLay and other futher readers make sure that when you use prepared statements in your programming language, you define the connection charset when you connect.. Otherwise character (multibyte) encoding injections might still lead to SQL injections..